# Traffic from two ports to one entrypoint?

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

In Kubernetes I use the Traefik ingress controller. My Kubernetes cluster is Bare Metal.

I have two services listening on ports 8080 and 8082. These two services are tied to one deployment. The deployment has an application that listens on these two ports for different tasks.

Can traffic be routed to these two ports through the same entrypoint, or is this not recommended?

Comment: What do you mean by entry point here?

Comment: Hi. That's what i mean https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/entrypoints/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with kubernetes, so excuse me if I misunderstood the question.

I'm running traefik with a single entry point on port 443 in front of multiple docker-compose services. That's no problem whatsoever. However, traefik needs to know which service the client wants to reach. This is done by specifying different host rules for these services. [see](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/#rule)